# how to overreide page.tpl.php with my custom menu

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have override page.tpl.php with my new custom menu created in my custom module. my menu look like below

```
$items['node/edit/restaurant/%/barcodes'] = array(
    'title'=>'Barcodes',
    'menu_name' => 'barcodes',
    'description'=>'Barcodes',
    'page callback'      => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('leo_MSTag_barcode', 5),
    'access callback'=>TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

I already try with `page--barcodes.tpl.php`, `page--node--edit--restaurant--barcodes.tpl.php` but not work for me. any new template suggestion for override mu menu page?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $patterns = 'node/edit/restaurant/*/barcodes';
  if (drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $patterns)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__edit__restaurant__barcodes';
  }
}
```

That would let you use `page--node--edit--restaurant--barcodes.tpl.php` after a cache clear.

As an aside, your `page arguments` are wrong in the router item, should be:

```
'page arguments' => array('leo_MSTag_barcode', 3), // <-- Index of arg is 3, not 5
```

Comment: thanks for quick replay but its not worked for me.

Comment: sorry my silly mistake i have put tpl file in my template folder instead of root theme folder. now its working thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use themeName_preprocess_page in your template.php.

Check the below url.

http://drupal.org/node/1089656.